# Setting SharePoint List Permission by row (Based on name of user)

Tags: sharepoint

Got a SharePoint List permissions question for you.

What I have is a huge list. One of the columns in this list has a "Person/Group" that's responsible for that item.

(The administrator creates the records (rows) and 'assigns' each row to a person, whose username goes into the "Person/Group" column)

I want SharePoint to allow the person in that column to have access to only see and edit that particular row. In other words, unless the person has been assigned to a row by the site administrator, they won't be able to see the row or edit it.

Example:

```
+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------------------+
| Title | Data 1 | Data 2 | Data 3 | Person responsible |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------------------+
| A     |      1 |      2 |      3 | Steve              |
| B     |      4 |      5 |      6 | Harry              |
| C     |      7 |      8 |      9 | Sally              |
| D     |     10 |     11 |     12 | Steve              |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------------------+
```

So in this table, Steve can only see and edit Row A and D. Harry can see and edit only column B. Sally can see and edit only column C.

What's the easiest way to achieve this, please? If it can be achieved at all.

I apologise if this is trivial/duplicate question.

P.s. I'm using SharePoint 2003 (I know.. I know.. Please don't hate me. It's not my decision.)

Thanks v. much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly there are no item level permissions in 2003. But even if you were using a later version of SharePoint having a huge list and item level permissions on each item would drastically reduce performance, see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg128955(v=office.15).aspx.

You could write a web part that displays the list items only for the logged in user but even that would be a PITA for SharePoint 2003.

Comment: I've done this exact thing in SP2010 via workflows without significant performance problems. The list had a few hundred entries; I suspect if there were a few thousand it could be different. Regardless, this won't work on 2003. Maybe Tim can use this lack of functionality as justification for getting a SharePoint update.

Comment: "Maybe Tim can use this lack of functionality as justification for getting a SharePoint update." - **I wish.**